# How to call function inside of other function

Tags: javascript, html

I've stuck while calling close function in below code. This program  create a new content respect to weekdays. After putting on to necessary place, if user want to delete the content the `close.setSttribute("onclick", "removeItem(this,event)");` function have to invoke. But in my code something gone wrong. Please help to fix to invoke that function.

```js
function addClick() {
  var weekday = document.getElementById("weekdaysModal").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  var itemContent = document.getElementById("textArea").value;

  var divItem = document.createElement("div");
  divItem.setAttribute("class", "divItem");
  var close = document.createElement("img");
  close.setAttribute("class", "close");
  close.setAttribute("src", "./img/delete.png");
  close.setAttribute("onclick", "removeItem(this, event)");
  close.setAttribute("width", "20px");
  close.setAttribute("height", "20px");
  console.log(close);
  divItem.appendChild(close);
  var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
  textDiv.setAttribute("class", "name");
  textDiv.innerHTML = name;
  divItem.appendChild(textDiv);
  var content = document.createElement('div');
  content.setAttribute("class", "itemContent");
  content.innerHTML = itemContent;
  content.style.display = 'none';
  divItem.appendChild(content);

  if (weekday == "monday") {
    //  divItem.setAttribute("index", monIndex);
    divItem.style.background = "#d4f442";
    document.getElementsByClassName('displayArea_mon')[0].appendChild(divItem);

  } else if (weekday == "tuesday") {
    //  divItem.setAttribute("index", tueIndex);
    divItem.style.background = "#65f441";
    document.getElementsByClassName('displayArea_tue')[0].appendChild(divItem);
  } else if (weekday == "wednesday") {
    console.log("wed");
    //  divItem.setAttribute("index", wedIndex);
    divItem.style.background = "#65f441";
    document.getElementsByClassName('displayArea_wed')[0].appendChild(divItem);
  } else if (weekday == "thursday") {
    //  divItem.setAttribute("index", thuIndex);
    divItem.style.background = "#65f441";
    document.getElementsByClassName('displayArea_thu')[0].appendChild(divItem);
  } else if (weekday == "friday") {
    //  divItem.setAttribute("index", friIndex);
    divItem.style.background = "#65f441";
    document.getElementsByClassName('displayArea_fri')[0].appendChild(divItem);
  } else {
    console.log("Error");
  }
  closeButton();
  console.log(name + content + weekday);
}

function removeItem() {
  var x = getElementsByClassName('divItem');
  x.delete(x.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Try this:
close.onclick = function(event){ removeItem(close, event)};

Comment: Also this: `document.querySelector('.displayArea_'+weekday.substring(0,3)).appendChild(divItem); divItem.style.background = weekday=="monday"?"#d4f442":"#65f441";`

Comment: But in this project not allowed to use J Query

Comment: The above is not jQuery - it is plain JS, and querySelector is even more compatible with old browsers than getElementsByClassName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: Also you pass the image to the removeItem - `x = getElementsByClassName('divItem');` item is not a select box and has not selectedIndex - perhaps you mean `function removeItem(img) {
  var x = img.closest("div.divItem") /* not supported in IE, so you need a shim */
  x.delete(x);
}`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Thank you very much for all! I have just changed to

Comment: function removeItem(img){
 var x= img.closest("div.divItem");
 x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}